# How to reach to Object tag contents by JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to reach to Object tag contents.
I have object tag and i need to reach some attribute value by JQuery, but it doesn't word for me. How can i solve it ?

**HTML like this**

```
<object width="100" height="100">
    <param name="movie" value="somevalue">
    <embed src="source" width="100" height="100">
</object>
```

**JQuery like this**

```
alert($("object").contents().find("param")).val());
```

It dos'nt work for me and i get NULL value !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are trying to use is not right. `$("object").contents().find("param")`

`$("object").contents()` --> give you the children of `object`

`find("param")` -->  will find in the descendants of the previous return value (children of `object`).

But according to the HTML structure you have, that is not what we want.

If we need to find value of the `param` element. We can just do

```
$("object").find("param").val()
```

as `param` by itself is a descendant of `object`

Please see this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/2QkHT/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to get.

Use `alert($("object").html());` if you want the entire HTML inside the object tag.

For just a single attribute use for example:

`alert($("object > param").attr("name"));`

If you want the html content of your param tag use:

`alert($("object > param").html());`

Comment: @EyadFarra please mark this a right answer if u think its correct